# My data set consists of many rows but only one column want to seperate the values from the one column into different columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset of thousands of rows and only one column. It was supposed to be 108 columns. All the values are seperated by tabs and I want to re-write this data frame with seperate columns in R. An example of one row is
"A_23_P149050\t-0.78007\t-0.43862\t0.26336\t-0.02076\t-0.11873\t0.30805\t-0.70170\t0.18403\t1.42516\t0.77827\t0.49341\t-0.07636\t0.00152\t0.55901"

It should be 15 different columns. With strsplit, I am getting a list and length still shows 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(a = "A_23_P149050\t-0.78007\t-0.43862\t0.26336\t-0.02076\t-0.11873\t0.30805\t-0.70170\t0.18403\t1.42516\t0.77827\t0.49341\t-0.07636\t0.00152\t0.55901")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>% 
  separate(col = a, into = paste("col", seq(1:15), sep= ""), sep = "\\t")

>df1
          col1     col2     col3    col4     col5
1 A_23_P149050 -0.78007 -0.43862 0.26336 -0.02076
      col6    col7     col8    col9   col10
1 -0.11873 0.30805 -0.70170 0.18403 1.42516
    col11   col12    col13   col14   col15
1 0.77827 0.49341 -0.07636 0.00152 0.55901
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `scan`.

```
scan(what='A', qui=T, text="A_23_P149050\t-0.78007\t-0.43862\t0.26336\t-0.02076\t-0.11873\t0.30805\t-0.70170\t0.18403\t1.42516\t0.77827\t0.49341\t-0.07636\t0.00152\t0.55901")
# [1] "A_23_P149050" "-0.78007"     "-0.43862"     "0.26336"      "-0.02076"     "-0.11873"     "0.30805"      "-0.70170"    
# [9] "0.18403"      "1.42516"      "0.77827"      "0.49341"      "-0.07636"     "0.00152"      "0.55901"
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` option:

```r
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("A_23_P149050\t-0.78007\t-0.43862\t0.26336\t-0.02076\t-0.11873\t0.30805\t-0.70170\t0.18403\t1.42516\t0.77827\t0.49341\t-0.07636\t0.00152\t0.55901"))
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, paste0("V", 1:15) := tstrsplit(V1, "\\t")]
df
#>              V1       V2       V3      V4       V5       V6      V7       V8
#> 1: A_23_P149050 -0.78007 -0.43862 0.26336 -0.02076 -0.11873 0.30805 -0.70170
#>         V9     V10     V11     V12      V13     V14     V15
#> 1: 0.18403 1.42516 0.77827 0.49341 -0.07636 0.00152 0.55901
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>